# Regex to capture trailing slash and query parameters but doesn't match if there's a file/directory after the trailing slash

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to create a Regex that will capture if the string:

- Is empty
- Is `/`
- Starts with `?`
- Starts with `/?`

But doesn't match something like `/foo` or `/foo/bar`.

So far I'm here:

```
(|/|/?\?.+)
```

but it's still matching `/foo` and `/foo/bar`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/odUfAp/1/ check this

Comment: Try `^(?!(?:/[^/]+)+/?$)(?:[/?].*)?$` or `^(?!(?:/[\w.-]+)+/?$)(?:[/?].*)?$`

Comment: You may use: `^/?(\?.+)?$`

Comment: To catch empty as well try this :     ^(?=[\/|\s]?[\s\?]+).*$

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex for your job:

```
^/?(\?.+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYR3vt/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `/?`: Match optional `/` at the start
- `(\?.+)?`: Match string starting with `? till end with 1+ characters after` ?`
- `$`: End